# How to convert an m3u8 to base64 encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding

I have clapper player andI i add url m3u8 and I need to encoding the url

this is the code:

```
   <script>
   var player = new Clappr.Player({source: 'http://vstream2.hadara.ps:8081/AlfajertvHD2_web/web1/playlist.m3u8',

parentId: '#player', mimeType: 'application/x-mpegURL',plugins: [DashShakaPlayback,LevelSelector,ChromecastPlugin],levelSelectorConfig: {
title: 'Quality',
labels: {
    2: 'High', // 500kbps
    1: 'Med', // 240kbps
    0: 'Low', // 120kbps
},
labelCallback: function(playbackLevel, customLabel) {
    return customLabel + playbackLevel.level.height+'p'; // High 720p
}
```

Comment: why do you need base64? is it not working like this?

Comment: no its work good . but i need to save the url so as notto be stolen

Comment: I don't get it then :)

Comment: i pay the url from company if any one open source page he will get it easy

Comment: I get it now. This is not an easy thing to do. Even if you encode the url with base64, anybody could see your source code, because it is javascript, so with little reverse engineering, they can find out the original url. This should be done on the other side, does the company you pay for offer some kind of encryption or authentication? They could allow requests only from your domain, or your ip, or of if they have a cdn, then aes encryption maybe..

Comment: This link costs me money and I do not want anyone to steal it through the operator's source. I have noticed in some sites you encrypt the link like this image
https://imgur.com/OrQOuZm

Comment: well that's one way to do it, but it is not safe at all. I can copy the window.atob('...') line to the browser console, and I can have the url, it is quite easy.. but if that is what you want to do, than here you go: window.atob('aHR0cDovL3ZzdHJlYW0yLmhhZGFyYS5wczo4MDgxL0FsZmFqZXJ0dkhEMl93ZWIvd2ViMS9wbGF5bGlzdC5tM3U4'); I used this site to generate it: https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: what about this code          source:  window.atob('<?php echo rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data['link']), '+/', '-_'), '='); ?>'),

Comment: this will work too, but you don't need to rtrim and strtr. This is enough: `window.atob('<?php echo base64_encode($data['link']);?>');`

Comment: but I still think, if you pay for it, the stream should be encrypted..

Comment: Can you write the code correctly and add the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work like this:

```
<script>
var player = new Clappr.Player({
    source: window.atob(<?php echo '"' . base64_encode($data['link']) . '"'; ?>),
    parentId: '#player',
    mimeType: 'application/x-mpegURL',
    plugins: [DashShakaPlayback,LevelSelector,ChromecastPlugin],
    levelSelectorConfig: {
        title: 'Quality',
        labels: {
            2: 'High', // 500kbps
            1: 'Med', // 240kbps
            0: 'Low', // 120kbps
        },
        labelCallback: function(playbackLevel, customLabel) {
            return customLabel + playbackLevel.level.height+'p'; // High 720p
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

But I still think, you should look up on the site where you bought the stream from, if they support any kind of encryption. The shaka player plugin which you are using, supports aes encryption, so it should be ok. You will probably need to implement some logic in php to sign the stream url.

Comment: inside the `base64_encode` function: `base64_encode('http://vstream2.hadara.ps:8081/AlfajertvHD2_web/web1/playlist.m3u8')`

Comment: you're welcome.. but are you sure, you don't want to ask the stream provider, if there is some encryption available on their side? :)

Comment: heheh yes im sure  because i ask them and tell me its will cost extra $